# AWT and Swing Tutorials

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am relatively new to programming in Java but have an understanding of the language to be able to develop console based programs.

I am trying to create and understand GUIs and have researched using AWT and Swing.

Having found numerous tutorials online and each one saying different things I am wandering if someone experienced in this could maybe point me in the right direction of a straight forward tutorial for getting a GUI set up and more specifically positioning of components!

I know this is quite a generalised question but I'm hoping someone who has maybe learnt this aspect of Java previously can point me to the right places to get a good understanding of it.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html

Comment: The 'good link' to the best tutorial is above. Just thought I'd take a moment to add: Swing components have effectively replaced (and expanded on) the AWT components that were available. But there is still a lot of the AWT referenced in that tutorial (e.g. most layouts & event listeners are AWT based..) because Swing is 'built on' core AWT functionality. So do that tutorial & you should be able to learn Swing and the parts of AWT that are still relevant.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had come across this but got put off by the NetBeans section, as I do not use NetBeans.  I presume this section can be missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java Oracle Docs is a good way to start. Parallely Go for Java Swing GUI Tutorials by Lazic B on youtube. After you feel good in coding go for Advanced Videos in building Swing MVC Application provided by Udemy. 3 months ago i have learned from these and now feel much confident in building high level swing applications

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Voting up due to the variety of suggestions.